# OpenERP v7: Sequence Number

Tags: odoo

How to make a sequence number increment by 10  in Openenerp

For Example:
In POLine have added new colum Line NO , When Adding an item Line no value should be set as increment by 10.

My Code:

```
'line_no':fields.integer('Line No'),
_defaults = {
    'line_no':lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order.line'),    
}
```

sequence.xml

```
<record id="seq_type_purchase_order_line" model="ir.sequence.type">
     <field name="name">Purchase Order Line</field>
     <field name="code">purchase.order.line</field>
</record>
<record id="seq_purchase_order_line" model="ir.sequence">
     <field name="name">Purchase Order Line</field>
     <field name="code">purchase.order.line</field>            
     <field name="padding">4</field>
     <field name="number_increment">10</field>
 </record>
```

I got the below error:

```
Error: [_.sprintf] expecting number but found string
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]what you have done, it is correct , you have done one single mistake,

you have to define 'line_no' as char type field not as integer

define like this: `'line_no':fields.char('Line No'),`

ir.sequence return string and your line_no is integer

what increment next number is return by get method is combile of prefix field,

```
interpolated_prefix + '%%0%sd' % seq['padding'] % seq['number_next'] + interpolated_suffix
```

so it is a string type sequence return from get method

Hope this help

Comment: means number display is 81,91++

Comment: so for this set next number to 10

Comment: in your code have mistake, add field in code of ir.sequence is Next Number set it to 10, other wise you will get this type of value

Comment: @updated my post@ let me do this sequence in openerp

Comment: yeah, so in sequnece update number_next_actual (Next Number) to 10

Comment: its all already increment number added in next number in database

Comment: so i added a picture for your refernce

Comment: Sequence error cleared, could you see my example in post , i didn't  get that solution.

Comment: '<field eval="10" name="number_next"/>'
'<field eval="10" name="number_increment"/>' use this way

Answer (score 0):

In xml you need to replace

```
<field name="number_increment">10</field>
```

by

```
<field eval="10" name="number_increment"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

check this code and you need to create one field for sequence No.

```
<field name="order_line" on_change="onchange_line(order_line)">

def onchange_line(self, cr, uid, ids, lines,context=None):
result = {}
result['value'] = {}
#do the proper checking
count_dict = {}
count = 10
had_seq = 0
for index,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line[0] == 0:
        count_dict[index] = count
        count +=10
    else:
        had_seq +=1
#seqnece_no is the new sequence field defined
for k in count_dict:
    if had_seq:
        lines[k][2]['sequence_no'] = had_seq*10 + count_dict[k]
    else:
        lines[k][2]['sequence_no'] = count_dict[k]
result['value'].update({'order_line':lines})
return result
```

hope this will help you

thanks @Odedra